# Printing the data received from the user to the screen with c

Tags: sql, arrays, c, for-loop

I'm trying to write a code that prints the contact information (name, surname, identity number, occupation) taken from the user one by one using a switch case, then collectively prints it to the screen in the form of a list. Could you help?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
int secim,loop=0;
long long int tc[3][2];
int i,j,n=0;
char ad[3][2];
char soyad[3][2];
char meslek[3][2];


while(loop==0){
        printf("\nSeciminizi Yapiniz:\n[1]BILGI GIRISI\n[2]LISTELEME\n[3]ARAMA\n[4]BILGI  SILME\n[5]SONLANDIR\n"); scanf("%d",&secim);

switch(secim){
    if(secim==1){
             n++; 
}
        case(1):// bilgi girisi
           for(j=0;j<1;j++){
                for(i=0;i<1;i++){
                    printf("Ad Giriniz: "); scanf("%s",&ad[i][j]); 
                    printf("Soyad Giriniz: "); scanf("%s",&soyad[i][j]); 
                    printf("Meslek giriniz "); scanf("%s",&meslek[i][j]);
                    printf("TC giriniz "); scanf("%lld",&tc[i][j]);
  }
  }

        break;

    case(2)://listeleme
     printf("-------------\n");

            for(j=0;j<n;j++){
                for(i=0;i<1;i++){
                    printf("Adi: %s\n",ad[i][j]); 
                    printf("Soyadi: %s\n",soyad[i][j]);
                    printf("Meslegi: %s\n",meslek[i][j]);
                    printf("Tc Numarasi: %lld\n",tc[i][j]);
                    printf("-------------\n");
  }
  }
    break;

    case(3):
        printf("3.secim\n");
    break;

    case(4):
        printf("4.secim\n");
    break;

    case(5):
        loop=1;
    break;
break;

}
}

return 0;
}
```

I think I'm making a mistake with arrays or for loop
AND MY OTHER CODE

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(){
int secim,loop=0;
char pool[]="Kullanici bilgileri \n", users[100];
int i;


while(loop==0){
        printf("\nSeciminizi Yapiniz:\n[1]BILGI     GIRISI\n[2]LISTELEME\n[3]ARAMA\n[4]BILGI SILME\n[5]SONLANDIR\n");         scanf("%d",&secim);
switch(secim){

        case(1):// bilgi girisi
            printf("\n Ad: "); scanf("%s", &users); strcat(pool,users); 
            printf("\n Soyad: "); scanf("%s", &users);     strcat(pool,users);
            printf("\n Meslek: "); scanf("%s", &users);     strcat(pool,users);
            printf("\n Kimlik: "); scanf("%s", &users); strcat(pool,users);
            
        break;

        case(2)://listeleme
        printf("%s",pool);
        break;

    }

return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: Look at the warnings and resolve them. They are there for a reason.

Comment: *Could you help?* Could you describe what is happening?

Comment: I enter the information, but only the last entered contact information is written on the screen. I want it to write all the information entered

Comment: I'm still a student and the information I have is not enough

Comment: Format your code so that the structure is readable. Please remove multiple instructions per line.

Answer (score 0):

In the first code section you compiler should warn you that the `if` will never execute. The `if` should be outside the `switch`.

```
switch(secim){
    if(secim==1){
```

---

Code like `strcat(pool,users);`  wil overflow the end of `pool`. Ditto for `char ad[3][2];` and similar.  There should be enough space to copy the strings is you add space for them in the declaration:

```
char pool[1024]="Kullanici bilgileri \n",
```

---

The compiler should warn you about weirdness at the location of these problems in the first code segment. Consider warnings as errors.